# Virtualbox What networkmode to use for server

Tags: virtualbox

I'm trying to figure out how to setup network in virtualbox for a linuxserver.
I want the server to be able to go to the internet, on the other hand I need it to have the same ip so I can add url's to my host's hostfile to access the websites on the server in the virtualbox.
Using NAT I have no control over the ip (i am often in different networks too)
using host-only the server has no internet..
What way should I go here?

Comment: You can set 2 different network adapters to your VM. One for NAT, second for host-only network.

Comment: And also you can use port forwarding on your NAT network. Look to the VM network settings.